# Origin of the word 烏有

Tags: words, kanji, etymology, archaic-language

I saw the phrase 烏有{うゆう}に帰{き}す, which means to "become nothing" as if turning to ashes. The word "烏有" means nothing, but its parts are 烏 (crow) and 有 (to be). How did 烏有 come to mean nothing?

When I consulted a dictionary ([kotobank.jp](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%83%8F%E6%9C%89-441691)), it said it means: 「烏(いずく)んぞ有らんや」. What does that mean? I'm not sure how to translate that. Also, is there a place where the word is first used?

Comment: I think you might actually ask about the origin of 烏有 on Chinese.SE.  All I can suggest is that 烏 was probably borrowed for its sound.

Comment: Here's more on this http://yuraika.com/uyunikisu/

Comment: @snailboat Seems rather to be an original Japanese simplification of 焉

Comment: @macraf Hmm, no, I don't think that's the case.  I think 烏 was used in Middle Chinese for its sound to write one of a class of ʔ-initial interrogatives (cf. 焉・安 and especially 惡, which was used to write the same word).  See Pulleyblank's *Outline of Classical Chinese Grammar* (1995) pages 91 and 96-97.

Comment: Chinese sources seem to pass it as some interrogative or negative indefinite pronoun. http://tw.18dao.net/%E6%88%90%E8%AA%9E%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E5%8C%96%E7%82%BA%E7%83%8F%E6%9C%89

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 烏有 as *on'yomi*: *uyū*

As others have noted in the question comments, 烏有 read as *uyū* derives from Classical Chinese.  Its origins there appear to be based on 烏 (not "*crow*" here, instead used phonetically in Middle Chinese as an interrogative and negative indefinite pronoun, as noted by snailboat and Derpius in the comments above) + 有 ("*to have, to be*") → "*none-have, none-be*" → "*nothing*".

### 烏有 as *kun'yomi*: *izukunzo aran'ya*

Addressing the latter portion of your question, いずくんぞあらんや is provided as the *kun'yomi* or native Japanese reading of the Classical Chinese term 烏有.  いずくんぞ again has no relation to the "*crow*" meaning of 烏, and あらんや implies the opposite of the "*to have, to exist*" meaning of 有, but the full *kun'yomi* is related to the Classical Chinese meaning of the full phrase.

#### The pieces: *izukunzo*

いずくんぞ is a contraction.  Walking it back:

- いずくんぞ
- いづく + に + ぞ
- いづこ (何【いづ】 "*which*" + 処【こ】 "*place*" → modern どこ) + に (locative particle) + ぞ (used in Classical Japanese after interrogatives to indicate non-specificity, apparently similar to the modern use of も as in どこにも)

いずくんぞ literally appears to mean "*wheresoever*".  In practice, its meaning was closer to "*why*" (perhaps similar to archaic English "*wherefore*").  The term mainly appears in Classical Japanese, in the *kundoku* (native Japanese recitation) of *kanbun* (works written in [broadly speaking] Classical Chinese).  いずくんぞ was used to introduce a supposition as part of a rhetorical question with an implied negative answer: "*why would [you think X, it be X, etc.] (because actually that's not the case).*"  One usage example given in Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten* is いずくんぞ知【し】らん: "*why would [someone] know it (when they probably don't).*"

#### The pieces: *aran'ya*

あらんや is similarly a contraction.

- あらんや
- あらむ (有る "*to be*" + supposition auxiliary む → modern あろう "*is it?, would it be?*") + や (question particle)

In Classical Japanese, the -む + や construction was used in rhetorical questions where the answer is assumed to be "no", somewhat like the English construction "*would it be X*" with intonation used to indicate a meaning of "*it isn't X*".

#### The full *kun'yomi* phrase

Putting it back together then, いずくんぞあらんや ultimately parses out to "*why would there be anything?*", intending "*there isn't anything*" → "*nothing*".