# Negation in 未然形 + む(ん)

Tags: classical-japanese, auxiliaries, particle-や

This question has been inspired by [this Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93422/what-form-is-being-used-in-%E5%8F%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A6#93429), from which I learned about 未然形 + む(ん)'s various functions. I noticed two lines on [the reference page @naruto points to](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009010.htm) under 推量, both seemingly sharing the same 未然形 + む(ん) structure. However, the first one is glossed as negative, while the second one translates in modern Japanese as a positive sentence.

> 推量…［～う・～だろう］
>
> 懈怠の心あることを**知らん**や。（徒然草・九二段）
> 　（怠けた心が生じることを**知らないだろう**か。）
>
> 夕には朝**あらん**ことを思ひ、朝には夕**あらん**ことを思ひて（徒然草・九二段）
> 　（夕方には明日の朝が**あるだろう**と思い、朝には夕方が**あるだろう**と思って）

Is there a reason for this? Or is this a mistake on the site editor's part?

Comment: Lol. I read this page a few months ago and faced this same confusion. I kinda got resolved by thinking 知らんや -> 知るだろうや -> 知らないだろうか. Take a look at this [や entry](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84). From the 係助詞 part:「③〔反語〕…（だろう）か、いや、…ない。」. Take me with a grain of salt, I might be wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example has 知らんや.  It's important to note the ending particle や -- this is used in Classical Japanese after a suppositional ～む ending to indicate a rhetorical question with an implied negative outcome, a bit like English construction "*would* he know that?" → implying that he wouldn't.

The あらん examples with ～ん (from older suppositional ～む) are not followed by this same negative-rhetorical particle, so the translations into modern Japanese phrasing do not include any negative sense.

See also:

- [This Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28850/origin-of-the-word-%e7%83%8f%e6%9c%89/29148#29148) about the term [烏有]{いずくんぞあらんや}, which includes that same ～むや construction.
- The Kotobank entries for や, such as [in Daijisen here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%84-647430#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89), specifically sense 六.2.イ: 「2.文末用法。㋑反語を表す。…だろうか（いや、そうではない）。」